# Are $C^1$ vector fields generating an ergodic flow $C^0$ dense?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

*Note: This is a concrete case of the following question: [Are almost all measure-preserving flows on compact manifolds ergodic?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408676/are-almost-all-measure-preserving-flows-on-compact-manifolds-ergodic.)*

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold with its natural Riemannian measure, and $V$ a $C^1$ vector field on $M$ whose associated flow is measure preserving.

Does there exist, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, a $C^1$ vector field $W$ that is $\varepsilon$-close to $V$ in $C^0$ norm such that the flow generated by $W$ is measure preserving and ergodic?

Comment: By the way, if the OP (of the linked question) was serious about "almost all", then asking for a dense set is a poor formalization, since then (for example) "almost all" real numbers are rational, or "almost all" continuous functions are polynomials etc.

Comment: The usual procedure on a complete metric space would be to ask for (at least) a dense $G_{\delta}$ set.

Comment: You probably want to add a reasonable assumption about the manifold so that it supports an ergodic flow, for instance, that your manifold is a torus of some dimension. The circle still provides a counter-example (because your $V$ can have stable zeroes). The first genuinely interesting case, I think, is $M=T^3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't always approximate by ergodic flows, because ergodic flows might not even exist.

For example, on $S^2$ the Poincare-Bendixson theorem rules out ergodic flows, but there are many measure-preserving flows.